# Move coupon form before subtotal in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, storefront

In my Storefront child theme, in the checkout page, I am trying to move the coupon code block just above the cart totals and below the item review
[image]

I see in `review-order.php` that there's the following hook just at the right place:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
```

So in the functions.php file, I added:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form' );
```

But, the coupon block appears twice...and above the order review instead of below.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2021** Use: [Move coupon form before payment section in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692133/move-coupon-form-before-payment-section-in-woocommerce-checkout/65696286#65696286)

As the hook `woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents` [is located inside an html table](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/checkout/review-order.php#L50) in between `</tr>` and `</tbody>` tags, so it requires to be displayed  inside a specific html structure, to avoid your issue.

The following will do that:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom' );
function woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom() {
    echo '<tr class="coupon-form"><td colspan="2">';
    
    wc_get_template(
        'checkout/form-coupon.php',
        array(
            'checkout' => WC()->checkout(),
        )
    );
    echo '</tr></td>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

---

If you want to display the coupon form directly, you can add the following in  style.css file oof your active child theme (or active theme):

```
.woocommerce-checkout .checkout_coupon.woocommerce-form-coupon {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Related: [Move coupon field after checkout payment in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011688/move-coupon-field-after-checkout-payment-in-woocommerce/47018982#47018982)

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAstec ! Thanks for your answer. It seems that it displays the coupon form at the right place, but then there a symbol that the form is updating and the coupon form disappears... any idea why ?

Comment: example here https://staging.hemen-biarritz.com/checkout/

Comment: doesn't work here. Maybe a plugin. I am checking now.

Comment: ok got it. I only display the part that containes `checkout_coupon woocommerce-form-coupon` so I had to `display: block !important` it

Comment: come on @LoicTheAztec, you're still the best !

Comment: This just moves the coupon form down in the checkout area.. How to make the message also appear down like "the coupon applied successfully" or "the coupon code doesn't exist"

Comment: Every body who looks for a better solution I would suggest this [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65696286/4170774).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Above Code is working good, But ajax is not working. Can you please help with the ajax.