# How to move the coupon field message in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, coupon

Using [Move coupon form before payment section in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692133/move-coupon-form-before-payment-section-in-woocommerce-checkout/65696286#65696286) answer code, I tried to move the coupon field and it is working perfectly, but I've just one problem: 
 On coupon validation, the validation/error message still appears on the bottom of the page.

How can I move the message under the new coupon field location?

Using this code on the functions.php, the validation/error message appears on the bottom page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.