# Trying to move the coupon form after "woocommerce_review_order_before_payment"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have tried to move the coupon code to the bottom of the checkout page at hook `"woocommerce_review_order_before_payment"` with this code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 5 );
```

The coupon code doesn't submit, I even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62893614/move-coupon-form-before-subtotal-in-woocommerce-checkout/62894898#62894898) code and it didn't solved the issue, does anyone know how to work with it?

Thanks

Comment: Which hook will keep it in the `<form>`?

Comment: Look here https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-cart-cart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by moving the coupon code with gift card field  into the table and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest the coupon form inside the checkout form. This will move the coupon form below the checkout form.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form');
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form' );
```

Comment: Is there a way to move the coupon form to the bottom of the page without CSS?

Comment: If you mean you want to remove or change the style, you could use custom CSS to change the appearance by modifying .woocommerce-form-coupon and/or other classes and ids.