# Woocommerce how to move coupon form to the bottom of the checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have tried removeing the `form-coupon.php` under the checkout template in woocommerce with this code on the child theme `functions.php` file with this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment' , 'coupon_code' );
 
function coupon_code() {
    if ( ! wc_coupons_enabled() ) { // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
    return;
    }
?>

<div class="coupon_code_form">
<form class="checkout_coupon woocommerce-form-coupon" method="post" style="display:none">
    <h4>ברשותך קוד קופון? הזיני כאן<h4/>
        <div id="coupon_redeem_form">
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'הזיני קוד קופון', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" />
        <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

For some reasons the form is shown but isn't sending out post, why this could happen?

Comment: please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

You could change its location by removing it from the top of the page, and adding it back in, at the bottom of the page.

You could remove the `coupon form` using the following code:

```php
remove_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10);
```

And in order to add it back, after `order review` section, you could use the following code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 5);
```

Or you could change the `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` hook according to where you would like to see the coupon form.

Code goes onto the `functions.php` file of your child theme!

This answer has been tested and works. Let me know if you could get it to work too!

Comment: It definitely works but we needed to remove some functionally from the coupon form, I think the function 'coupon_code' isn't working properly

Comment: The form isnt sumbitting, see for yourself -> https://woocommerce-620267-2036098.cloudwaysapps.com/checkout/

Comment: Does any of these links help you? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47018982/15040627), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62894898/15040627).

Comment: No actually, I tried both, this is the last one on the site -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62893614/move-coupon-form-before-subtotal-in-woocommerce-checkout/62894898#62894898

Comment: If I moved the hook to `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` the form doesn't submit